# R glm() without including training dataset

Tags: r, glm

What argument do I need to pass to the `glm()` call in order to NOT include the training dataset in the glm object which can be very big at times?

Answer (score 2):

Wow, missed this from 30min of googling:

```
y=FALSE and model=FALSE
```